# Does react-router need specific guidance when using Flow types?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, flowtype

I have the following fairly simple React component.

Because it's a navigational component, I'm using `withRouter` to gain access to the `RouterHistory` object.

I'm also using Flow for typing and I have the `flow-typed` filed for `react-router_v4`

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';
import type {RouterHistory} from 'react-router';

import '../sass/Link.scss';

type Props = {
  disabled?: boolean,
  href: string,
  className?: string,
  history: RouterHistory,
  children: *,
};

const Link = ({history, href, disabled, children, className}: Props) => (
  <span
    className={classnames(['link', className, {disabled}])}
    onClick={() => history.push(href)}>
    {children}
  </span>
);

Link.defaultProps = {
  className: '',
  disabled: false,
};

export default withRouter(Link);
```

When I run my Flow check, it churns out the following errors:

```
Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ components/Link.jsx:17:14

Property className is missing in object type [1] but exists in Props [2] in the first argument.

     components/Link.jsx
      14│   children: *,
      15│ };
      16│
 [2]  17│ const Link = ({history, href, disabled, children, className}: Props) => (
      18│   <span
      19│     className={classnames(['link', className, {disabled}])}
      20│     onClick={() => history.push(href)}>
      21│     {children}
      22│   </span>
      23│ );
      24│
      25│ Link.defaultProps = {
      26│   className: '',

     flow-typed/npm/react-router_v4.x.x.js
 [1] 120│     Component: React$ComponentType<{| ...ContextRouter, ...P |}>


Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ components/Link.jsx:17:14

Property disabled is missing in object type [1] but exists in Props [2] in the first argument.

     components/Link.jsx
      14│   children: *,
      15│ };
      16│
 [2]  17│ const Link = ({history, href, disabled, children, className}: Props) => (
      18│   <span
      19│     className={classnames(['link', className, {disabled}])}
      20│     onClick={() => history.push(href)}>
      21│     {children}
      22│   </span>
      23│ );
      24│
      25│ Link.defaultProps = {
      26│   className: '',

     flow-typed/npm/react-router_v4.x.x.js
 [1] 120│     Component: React$ComponentType<{| ...ContextRouter, ...P |}>
```

Trying to decipher the error message, I tried changing my export to:

```
export default withRouter<Props>(Link);
```

But that just generates the error:

```
Cannot call withRouter with Link bound to Component because function [1] is incompatible with statics of
React.Component [2].
```

I feel like I'm missing something here - it seems like the typing here is all above board, but I'm getting these errors. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Props` type, `className` and `disabled` are optional. But then later, in the component, you are trying to use them without checking if they are present:

```
className={classnames(['link', className, {disabled}])}
```

The quick fix is to just check if either of those values are null and give them default values if they are:

```
const Link = ({history, href, disabled, children, className}: Props) => (
  <span
    className={classnames(['link', className ? className : '', {Boolean(disabled)}])}
    onClick={() => history.push(href)}>
    {children}
  </span>
);
```

The type checker is giving you slightly misleading errors:

> Property className is missing in object type [1] but exists in Props [2] in the first argument.
>
> Property disabled is missing in object type [1] but exists in Props [2] in the first argument.

I guess it is inferring that the arguments are non-null because of how they are being used and then finding that this does not match the type of `Props`.